# HTTP If-Modified-Since with milliseconds

Tags: http, http-headers

Let's say I get an object from REST web service and this object has a time stamp. This time stamp has a milliseconds component. Next time I request the same object I don't want it to be returned unless it has changed, so I use the If-Modified-Since header. But the date in that header is not even supposed to have milliseconds. If I round the time stamp down, I'll always get the object back as if it's always modified. If I round it up I risk missing some updates. Is the If-Modified-Since header completely useless to me in this case, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 16):

A service that sends a time stamp with milliseconds is not HTTP-compliant.   [`Last-Modified`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) MUST be sent as a *HTTP-date* which [§3.3.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1) specifies very clearly:

> ```
> HTTP-date    = rfc1123-date | rfc850-date | asctime-date
> rfc1123-date = wkday "," SP date1 SP time SP "GMT"
> rfc850-date  = weekday "," SP date2 SP time SP "GMT"
> asctime-date = wkday SP date3 SP time SP 4DIGIT
> date1        = 2DIGIT SP month SP 4DIGIT
>               ; day month year (e.g., 02 Jun 1982)
> date2        = 2DIGIT "-" month "-" 2DIGIT
>               ; day-month-year (e.g., 02-Jun-82)
> date3        = month SP ( 2DIGIT | ( SP 1DIGIT ))
>               ; month day (e.g., Jun  2)
> time         = 2DIGIT ":" 2DIGIT ":" 2DIGIT
>               ; 00:00:00 - 23:59:59
> wkday        = "Mon" | "Tue" | "Wed"
>             | "Thu" | "Fri" | "Sat" | "Sun"
> weekday      = "Monday" | "Tuesday" | "Wednesday"
>             | "Thursday" | "Friday" | "Saturday" | "Sunday"
> month        = "Jan" | "Feb" | "Mar" | "Apr"
>             | "May" | "Jun" | "Jul" | "Aug"
>             | "Sep" | "Oct" | "Nov" | "Dec"
> ```

File a bug with the service you are using.  It is invalid to send `Last-Modified` or `If-Modified-Since` with milliseconds.

If sub-second accuracy is important, it may be more appropriate to use [entity tags (`ETag`)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.11).

Comment: The time stamp I'm receiving is not coming as Last-Modified header, it's a property of the object itself. I wanted to send it back using If-Modified-Since.

Comment: @JoeShmo: The answer holds.  `If-Modified-Since` MUST be a *HTTP-date* as well (meaning you can't send milliseconds), and the service you're using must support it.  Without knowing more about the service in question, it's hard to say much more.